# Why does my statement end in the middle for certain input

Tags: java, if-statement, printing

I'm still dealing with the project and I have spent countless numbers of sleepless nights trying to figure this out and I just cant anymore.So the issue is I'm supposed to calculate a bonus value for numbers above `10` and below `10` and the statements are stated below. The issue is it works if I use all `+ve` values(above `1` in this case bonus will be `-ve` if the input is below `10`). When I input a value that is less than `10` `(str<10)` it only prints the `str` value and stops without giving the output for the other 6 variables. If I enter a number above `10` `(str>10)` the entire program works the exact way i want it giving out the relevant output for the other 6 variables as well.

I think something is wrong with the `str` as I checked one by one by inputting values below `10`(the output of the bonus is `-ve`)  to other 6 variables after `str` keeping the `str` value above `10` always and it works. But when I enter a value to `str` below `10` the only the first 2 print statements are printed and the program ends. Please help. Thank you

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Please 
{
    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int bonusstr = 0,bonusdex = 0,bonuscon=0,bonusintel=0,bonuswise=0,bonuschara=0;

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Level");
        int Level= sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter Str value");
        int str =sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter dex value");
        int dex =sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter con value");
        int con =sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter int value");
        int intel =sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter wise value");
        int wise =sc.nextInt();


        System.out.print("Enter cha value");
        int chara =sc.nextInt();

        if(str==10)
        {
            bonusstr=0;
        }
        else if(str%2==0 && str>10)
        {
            bonusstr=(str-10)/2;
        }
        else if(str%2==1 && str>10)
        {
            bonusstr=((str-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(str%2==0 && str<10)
        {
            bonusstr=(str-10)/2;
        }
        else if(str%2==1 && str<10)
        {
            bonusstr=((str-10)-1)/2;
        }

        if(dex==10)
        {
            bonusdex=0;
        }
        else if(dex%2==0 && dex>10)
        {
            bonusdex=(dex-10)/2;
        }
        else if(dex%2==1 && dex>10)
        {
            bonusdex=((dex-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(dex%2==0 && dex<10)
        {
            bonusdex=(dex-10)/2;
        }
        else if(dex%2==1 && dex<10)
        {
            bonusdex=((dex-10)-1)/2;
        }

        if(con==10)
        {
            bonuscon=0;
        }
        else if(con%2==0 && con>10)
        {
            bonuscon=(con-10)/2;
        }
        else if(con%2==1 && con>10)
        {
            bonuscon=((con-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(con%2==0 && con<10)
        {
            bonuscon=(con-10)/2;
        }
        else if(con%2==1 && con<10)
        {
            bonuscon=((con-10)-1)/2;
        }

        if(intel==10)
        {
            bonusintel=0;
        }
        else if(intel%2==0 && intel>10)
        {
            bonusintel=(intel-10)/2;
        }
        else if(intel%2==1 && intel>10)
        {
            bonusintel=((intel-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(intel%2==0 && intel<10)
        {
            bonusintel=(intel-10)/2;
        }
        else if(intel%2==1 && intel<10)
        {
            bonusintel=((intel-10)-1)/2;
        }

        if(wise==10)
        {
            bonuswise=0;
        }
        else if(wise%2==0 && wise>10)
        {
            bonuswise=(wise-10)/2;
        }
        else if(wise%2==1 && wise>10)
        {
            bonuswise=((wise-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(wise%2==0 && wise<10)
        {
            bonuswise=(wise-10)/2;
        }
        else if(wise%2==1 && wise<10)
        {
            bonuswise=((wise-10)-1)/2;
        }

        if(chara==10)
        {
            bonuschara=0;
        }
        else if(chara%2==0 && chara>10)
        {
            bonuschara=(chara-10)/2;
        }
        else if(chara%2==1 && chara>10)
        {
            bonuschara=((chara-10)-1)/2;
        }
        else if(chara%2==0 && chara<10)
        {
            bonuschara=(chara-10)/2;
        }
        else if(chara%2==1 && chara<10)
        {
            bonuschara=((chara-10)-1)/2;
        }

        System.out.print("\nLevel \t"+Level+"");
        if(str<10)
        {
            System.out.print("\nStr \t"+str+"["+bonusstr+"]");
        }
        else if(str>10)
        {
            System.out.print("\nStr \t"+str+"[+"+bonusstr+"]");

            if(dex<10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nDex \t"+dex+"["+bonusdex+"]");
            }
            else if(dex>10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nDex \t"+dex+"[+"+bonusdex+"]");
            }

            if(con<10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nCon \t"+con+"["+bonuscon+"]");
            }
            else if(con>10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nCon \t"+con+"[+"+bonuscon+"]");
            }

            if(intel<10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nIntel \t"+intel+"["+bonusintel+"]");
            }
            else if(intel>10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nIntel \t"+intel+"[+"+bonusintel+"]");
            }

            if(wise<10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nwise \t"+wise+"["+bonuswise+"]");
            }
            else if(wise>10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nWise \t"+wise+"[+"+bonuswise+"]");
            }

            if(chara<10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nChara \t"+chara+"["+bonuschara+"]");
            }
            else if(chara>10)
            {
                System.out.print("\nChara \t"+chara+"[+"+bonuschara+"]");
            }

            double hitpoints= Level*(Math.random()*1000 %6+1);
            System.out.print("\nhp \t"+hitpoints+" ");
        }            
    }

}
```

Comment: Countless sleepless nights? Your code does what you have programmed.  In your last "mega-if-block" if (str < 10) you just print Str, the other values are only printed if (str > 10). One tip: if you do the same thing in both part of an if-else block, just execute the inner sentence without conditions. Your last "mega-if-block" makes no sense and you don't print the variables if they are exactly equals to 10.

Comment: there are many scanners..not sure the purpose of each one. Could you helps us explain what is the significant of each variable or just give the console where the program was a success and failed

Comment: @Jayanth  . As you said if the input value==10 for any of the variables the bonus that needs to be printed is 0 , all tho since i dont have a print statement for that the program skips it if i enter 10. Im very new to programming  . Its actually the dungeons of Dragons basic game. I heard that i can do all the calculation in side a method and call it , iv tried to read about it but didnt find anything that was proper or understanding to my basic knowledge. Thats why i had to write so many scanners, print lines and if statements . I dont know how to and im trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not written the code in `if` statement.

It have only following code:

```
    System.out.print("\nLevel \t"+Level+"");
    if(str<10)
    {
        System.out.print("\nStr \t"+str+"["+bonusstr+"]");
    }
```

Add required code in this if statement.

**Note:**

- You have not considered `==` condition in several places in your code e.g. In following *What code part should execute if `dex is 10`*

  ```
     if(dex<10)
      {
          System.out.print("\nDex \t"+dex+"["+bonusdex+"]");
      }
      else if(dex>10)
      {
          System.out.print("\nDex \t"+dex+"[+"+bonusdex+"]");
      }
  ```
- You have unnecessorly used `if-else` statements. Above code is an example. You are doing the same thing in both part(what are you doing in `if` you are doing the same in `else`)

Answer (score -1):

```
if(str<10){
    System.out.print("\nStr \t"+str+"["+bonusstr+"]");
}else if(str>10){
    System.out.print("\nStr \t"+str+"[+"+bonusstr+"]");"
```

You forgot to close the else if

Comment: Also is there anyway that i can write multiple if statements like these in one

Comment: Why not using a method named printStat(String statName, int value). It would do a System.out.println(statname + value) and you could then replace all your if-else by switch() and call that method with the appropriate parameters. You could also create a method for reading keyboard values.